# PHP DOM Parser parse html table

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom

How to use the PHP DOM Parser to parse the content of the table, so I get:

- the username
- the mobilephone number
- the status

So the output of what I try to extract would be:

- randomusername - 0123456789 - active
- randomusername2 - 0987654321 - active

This is the html i try to parse (some part of it):

```
...
<div class="table tbl-process-mobile">
  <div class="table-cn">
    <div class="table-bd">
      <table cellspacing="0" id="idd7">

<thead>
    <tr id="idd9">
        <th scope="col">
          <span>username</span>
        </th>
        <th scope="col">
          <span>status</span>
        </th>

        <th scope="col">        
          <span>prefered number</span>
        </th>

        <th scope="col">
          <span>action</span>
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody id="iddb">
    <tr class="even">
        <td class="even">
            <div>randomusername</div>
        </td><td class="odd">
            <div>0123456789</div>
        </td><td class="even">
            <div>active</div>
        </td><td class="odd">
            <div>
  <span id="iddc" style="display:none"></span>
  <a href="xyz" id="idb2"><span>set number</span></a>
</div>
        </td><td class="even">
            <div>
  <a id="iddd" style="display:none"></a>
  <a href="xyz" class="action-icon-edit" id="idb3" title="change">
    <i>change</i>
  </a>
  <a href="xyz" class="action-icon-delete" id="idb4" title="delete">
    <i>delete</i>
  </a>
</div>
        </td>
    </tr><tr class="odd">
        <td class="even">
            <div>randomusername2</div>
        </td><td class="odd">
            <div>0987654321</div>
        </td><td class="even">
            <div>active</div>
        </td><td class="odd">
            <div>
  <span id="idde" style="display:none"></span>
  <a href="xyz" id="idb5"><span>set number</span></a>
</div>
        </td><td class="even">
            <div>
  <a id="iddf" style="display:none"></a>
  <a href="xyz" class="action-icon-edit" id="idb6" title="change">
    <i>change</i>
  </a>
  <a href="xyz" class="action-icon-delete" id="idb7" title="delete">
    <i>delete</i>
  </a>
</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
...
```

I already started with some PHP code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
$matches = array();
$dom = new DOMDocument;

$dom->loadHTMLFile('settings.html');
```

How to extract the values, what's the best way to parse the HTML from this point?

Comment: Iterate over each `tr`.

Comment: Which value you need .. the ones related to a tag? .. to an id ? ..

Comment: Sidenote: Should there be any errors somewhere related to either PHP or an incorrect file path, `error_reporting(0);` won't help. It's best to catch and display during testing.

Comment: @scaisEdge take a look above, I showed the things I need to extract!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$field_names = ['username', 'phone', 'status'];
$result = [];

// Search for div tags having tbl-process-mobile class
$containers = $doc->getElementsByTagName('div');
foreach ($containers as $container) {
  if (!isset($container->attributes['class']))
    continue;

  if (false === strpos($container->attributes['class']->value,
    'tbl-process-mobile'))
    continue;

  // Assume that tbody tags are required
  if (!$tbodies = $container->getElementsByTagName('tbody'))
    continue;

  // Get the first tbody (there should not be more)
  if (!$tbodies->length || !$tbody = $tbodies->item(0))
    continue;

  foreach ($tbody->getElementsByTagName('tr') as $tr) {
    $i = 0;
    $row = [];
    $cells = $tr->getElementsByTagName('td');

    // Collect the first count($field_names) cell values as maximum
    foreach ($field_names as $name) {
      if (!$td = $cells->item($i++))
        break;
      $row[$name] = trim($td->textContent);
    }

    if ($row)
      $result []= $row;
  }
}

var_dump($result);
```

*Sample Output*

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["username"]=>
    string(14) "randomusername"
    ["phone"]=>
    string(10) "0123456789"
    ["status"]=>
    string(6) "active"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["username"]=>
    string(15) "randomusername2"
    ["phone"]=>
    string(10) "0987654321"
    ["status"]=>
    string(6) "active"
  }
}
```

No comments, as the code is self-explanatory.

P.S.: in the sense of parsing, the HTML structure leaves a lot to be desired.

Answer (score 0):

You can use selector methods of [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) class like [`getElementById()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementbyid.php) and [`getElementsByTag()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) to find target elements. After finding elements, get text of it and store in array.

```
$trs = $dom->getElementById("iddb")->getElementsByTagName("tr");
$arr = [];
foreach($trs as $key=>$tr){
    $tds = $tr->getElementsByTagName("td");
    $arr[$key] = [
        $tds->item(0)->textContent,
        $tds->item(1)->textContent,
        $tds->item(2)->textContent
    ];
}
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/Kidpo)

Also you can use [`DOMXPath`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) class to find target elements.

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$trs = $xpath->query("//tbody/tr");
```

Answer (score -1):

Try use `strip_tags`

```
$html='<div class="table tbl-process-mobile">
  <div class="table-cn">
    <div class="table-bd">
      <table cellspacing="0" id="idd7">

<thead>
    <tr id="idd9">
        <th scope="col">
          <span>username</span>
        </th>
        <th scope="col">
          <span>status</span>
        </th>

        <th scope="col">        
          <span>prefered number</span>
        </th>

        <th scope="col">
          <span>action</span>
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody id="iddb">
    <tr class="even">
        <td class="even">
            <div>randomusername</div>
        </td><td class="odd">
            <div>0123456789</div>
        </td><td class="even">
            <div>active</div>
        </td><td class="odd">
            <div>
  <span id="iddc" style="display:none"></span>
  <a href="xyz" id="idb2"><span>set number</span></a>
</div>
        </td><td class="even">
            <div>
  <a id="iddd" style="display:none"></a>
  <a href="xyz" class="action-icon-edit" id="idb3" title="change">
    <i>change</i>
  </a>
  <a href="xyz" class="action-icon-delete" id="idb4" title="delete">
    <i>delete</i>
  </a>
</div>
        </td>
    </tr><tr class="odd">
        <td class="even">
            <div>randomusername2</div>
        </td><td class="odd">
            <div>0987654321</div>
        </td><td class="even">
            <div>active</div>
        </td><td class="odd">
            <div>
  <span id="idde" style="display:none"></span>
  <a href="xyz" id="idb5"><span>set number</span></a>
</div>
        </td><td class="even">
            <div>
  <a id="iddf" style="display:none"></a>
  <a href="xyz" class="action-icon-edit" id="idb6" title="change">
    <i>change</i>
  </a>
  <a href="xyz" class="action-icon-delete" id="idb7" title="delete">
    <i>delete</i>
  </a>
</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>';

echo strip_tags($html);
```

**Updated:**

You parse DOM elements using `getElementsByTagName`

Read all td

```
$td=$dom->getElementsByTagName('td');
```

loop through td and read the div contents

```
foreach($td as $t){
$div=$t->getElementsByTagName('div');
foreach($div as $d){
    echo $d->textContent;
}
```

}

Here above will get all the div contents but we only the particular div elements so I suggest you to put some class or data attributes for divs which you want to retrieve. Then put the if condition inside the loop. Here I put ***data*** class.

```
 foreach($td as $t){
$div=$t->getElementsByTagName('div');
foreach($div as $d){
    if($d->getAttribute('class')=='data'){
     echo $d->textContent;
   }

}}
```

Comment: No, this will just be chaos. Why break the structured data!

Comment: what you mean?.

Comment: I would like to extract the values into values, not this way. This is a chaos as @chris85 mentioned.

Comment: There is no organization this way. How will you know (programmatically) what the username is, phone number, etc. This is NOT how parsing is done.

Comment: So you want get the particular element's value. Right?

Comment: @SarathKumar I explained above what "elements" I need.

Comment: The OP wants to extract data, not strip it. Please read the question again. @SarathKumar

Comment: I got it.Writing my answer!